# Funcion para mostrar fecha actual

Tags: php

Tengo dos líneas para que me devuelva la fecha actual en formato fecha y no en string, pero no me devuelve nada:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$hoy = new DateTime($date);
```

Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Para mostrar la fecha actual ha de efectuar new Datettime('now'), tal y como se indica en la guía de php (http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php)

Comment: Haz var_dump($hoy); y veras que lo tienes: Object(DateTime)#1 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2018-10-22 10:23:20.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(16) "America/New_York" }

Comment: Quieres obtener la fecha en `string` para imprimirla por pantalla ? esa es la pregunta ?

Comment: He conseguido mostrar la fecha actual con la siguiente funcion: `$hoy=strftime( "%Y-%m-%d" );`

Comment: @Xerox viene a ser lo mismo que date("Y-m-d"); ¿para qué convertías en objeto DateTime?

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu objetivo final? ¿Obtener una instancia de `DateTime` con la fecha actual o saber qué formato necesitas proporcionar como parámetro para poder introducir una fecha arbitraria?

Answer (score 1):

Como dijeron en la respuesta anterior, te falta definir el formato de salida de tu fecha:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Lima');
$hoy = date("Y-m-d");
$date = new DateTime($hoy );
// En la siguiente linea defines la manera como quieres que se muestr tu fecha, puedes agregar o quitar los campos que desees,segun tus necesidades. Por ejemplo:
echo $date->format('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
```

Answer (score 0):

Tengo entendido que para mostrar la fecha utilizando **date** es necesario realizar la declaración como se hace en la documentación, de esta manera:

```
<?php
// Establecer la zona horaria predeterminada a usar. Disponible desde PHP 5.1
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');


// Imprime algo como: Monday
echo date("l");

// Imprime algo como: Monday 8th of August 2005 03:12:46 PM
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');

// Imprime: July 1, 2000 is on a Saturday
echo "July 1, 2000 is on a " . date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2000));

/* Usar las constantes en el parámetro de formato */
// Imprime algo como: Wed, 25 Sep 2013 15:28:57 -0700
echo date(DATE_RFC2822);

// Imprime algo como: 2000-07-01T00:00:00+00:00
echo date(DATE_ATOM, mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2000));
?>
```